# FOSS Office-Space-Management Software

Tags: open-source

I have been entrusted with the thankless task of taking over the office-space management in our company. In the last few years, there have always been problems because we have too many employees for too little space. Everything is very confusing at the moment and no one really knows who works where, how and why. There are conference rooms, group rooms and employees who only use their offices part-time.
Is there a good software that helps me to catalog the available resources, to define usage times, to record equipment, size and e.g. number of workstations per office and manage those resources?
We have several hundred employees, as well as several hundred individual and multi-person offices, plus special rooms with a wide range of equipment, meeting rooms, and other facilities.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest taking a look at the various resources here:
[list-open-source-software-for-resource-scheduling-and-booking](https://edgeryders.eu/t/list-open-source-software-for-resource-scheduling-and-booking/6629)

[BookedScheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/) used to be open source. But is now SaaS. The last opensource code can be found [here](https://github.com/effgarces/BookedScheduler).

Because you need to track not only rooms, but equipment, you may have to be creative in terms of how items are created.